# R' Elazar Shach's polemic against Chabad

Tags: rabbis, chabad

There are numerous reports that the late R. Elazar Shach fought a bitter battle against Chabad, even using harsh language in his campaign.  If these reports are true, I wonder why this rabbi was so angry with Chabad? This cannot have been simple opposition to Hasidism as his attack was directed at only one Hasidic group. Nor could it have been directed against the veneration of the last rebbe as the messiah as this is not and never was the dominant view of the Chabad community.

Comment: A similar question was asked and closed here - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70987/rav-shach-and-lubavitsher-rebbe/71021#71021

Comment: I think such a question is walking a delicate tightrope as it will very likely give rise to needless loshon hora for two chashuve rabbonim.

Comment: The key word is 'needless' - some people think that the more puzzling parts of the rabbis should be understood and some people prefer to pretend that that rabbis never do or say things which leave ordinary Jews confused.

Comment: It has almost everything to do with Chabad Messianism. I suggest you read what you can find on the matter from the internet as well as what's in the Telushkin book if you have it. Chabad's "official" stance is that the Rebbe is not the Moshiach, however coming from Chabad I will have you know it is much, much more widespread than Chabad lets on. Contact me thru the info in my bio, I'd love to talk more about it.

Comment: @Moshe Yes that's the book I mean. This question isn't really on topic for the site that's why I want to talk with you about it outside

Comment: Can you give examples of such reports?

Comment: Here is a newspaper report from 1993 where R' Shach is said to have used rather strong language against Chabad messianism: https://ranaz.co.il/Images/articles/newsp2/n19930131_1.jpg

Comment: A 1983 newspaper report also quotes R' Shach as using quite strong language against Chabad. https://www.nli.org.il/he/newspapers/dav/1983/11/25/01/article/95/?e=-------he-20--1--img-txIN%7ctxTI--------------1

Comment: see https://identifyingchabad.org

Comment: All *chassidus* was controversial, some would say it still is.

Comment: @pcoz The important word is was. Nowadays, only Chabad, Breslov, and maybe Satmar are really controversial. And as the OP pointed out, Rav Shach had good relations with other Chassidic Rebbes, especially the Belzer Rebbe shlita"a.

Comment: @MosheWise So according to the 1993 article, the "Rebbe" actually approved designs for a crown for when he would be appointed Mashiach? Wow.

Comment: he had a view of Chabad based on his understanding and he fought against his view of Chabad. If only he had understood Chabad Chassidus and the Rebbe from the actual point of view of Chabad then there would have been nothing to fight angrily against. There are always differences of opinion on things but not always a reason to fight. When we can stop and appreciate someone's shita from his perspective then there isn't a straw man to fight against.

Comment: In other words, R' Shach

Answer (score 3):

*Nor could it have been directed against the veneration of the last rebbe as the messiah as this is not and never was the dominant view of the Chabad community.*

Firstly I wish, wish, wish that this were the case.

Secondly it wasn't only the messianism. It was also their lifting of their rebbe almost to the point of deification R'L

See here for more details

https://identifyingchabad.org/index.html

Comment: Interesting, even though that’s still not heresy is it? As long as they keep the Law. Many rabbis thought they were the messiah...the Rebbe didn’t

Comment: It's not entirely clear that he didn't think of himself as being moshiach, based on cryptic statements he made that his followers may or may not have misinterpreted.